# Driver output to FET gate voltage - rise & fall time

Tags: mosfet, driver, mosfet-driver, powermosfet

I have an ISO driver with the following params: Peak source current = 4 A, Peak sink current = 6 A, Sink resistance = 0.55 ohm, source resistance = 5 ohm.

**How do I calculate the time between the rise/fall to 50% Voa to Vth of the FET?**
The FET has 1 ohm gate resistance, and an external 47 ohm get resistor, as well as an external Vgs capacitor of 10 nF, image below:

[image]

Comment: Why the external Cgs capacitor is needed? For the correct calculation you should look into a datasheet for Gate charge VS. Vgs, then read some paper from TI, Infineon, IOR, Analog Devices, LT...which describes this with all needed equations.

Comment: to slow opening and closing of fet

Comment: Which FET, and what is the load on the Drain?